# Checksum on string

Tags: linux, bash, checksum

Is there a way to calculate a checksum on a string in Linux? The checksum commands that I have seen (`cksum`, `md5sum`, `sha1sum`, etc.) all require a file as input and I do not have a file. I only have a path to a location and want to calculate the checksum on that path.

Comment: @Flimzy: That would try to run `md5sum` on a file at that location, not on the string itself.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
echo -n 'exampleString' | md5sum
```

should work.

Comment: How can I get a CRC32 instead of MD5 checksum? Thank you.

Comment: The only issue is that CRLF and LF line break types will output different hashsum, so have to be careful about the environment and the terminal used.

Answer (score 20):

```
echo -n "yourstring" |md5sum
echo -n "yourstring" |sha1sum
echo -n "yourstring" |sha256sum
```

don't forget -n or the result will change (cuz the newline will be parsed)

Comment: @ gniourf_gniourf stay easy, i gived  the answer to him, with and without my code.. btw  ./gensum -t gniourf_gniourf
md5: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
sha1:  adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc  -
sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
 it  works.

Comment: And by the way, [these are not the correct hash sums of `gniourf_gniourf`](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=gniourf_gniourf).

Comment: Oh, sorry man i edit my answer, ok? Yes, i saw the problem for the hash

Comment: But now, in what is your answer different from the previous accepted answer?

Comment: Sharon asked for sha1, sha256 and md5, i gived all the 3 and btw i didn't see the epoch, sorry again oh and problem solved in the script :P